# What are examples of stimuli that we know cause a grief or sadness reaction in humans?

Tags: social-psychology, emotion

I am looking for examples of stimuli that has been shown to cause sadness in humans in a controlled environment as opposed to the neurological basis or evolutionary reason for sadness

Answer (score 1):

I m not sure how much of sadness images are covered under it but perhaps you could have a look at IAPS ( International Affective Picture Series) . They seek to make media for specifically inducing desired affective states in research work including images , audios and videos.

http://csea.phhp.ufl.edu/media.html

Perhaps you could have a look into Mood Inducing Procedures ( MIP) used to induce both positive and negative affects in a laboratory setting .